# How can I read tokens with an amount of 0 with getParsedProgramAccounts?

Tags: web3.js, nft, getprogramaccounts

I am developing an application. I read the tokens by using getParsedProgramAccounts. In the last weeks I read the tokens with amount of 0 to see which were once connected with the program Id. However, today a friend tried my application and he could not find his tokens with amount of 0. I checked it too, and the method does not respond them anymore. A few weeks ago, the method respond them.

What can I do to see the tokens with amount of 0?

This is my code:

```
let programmAccount = await connection.getParsedProgramAccounts(
  TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
  {
    filters: [
      {
        dataSize: 165, // number of bytes
      },
      {
        memcmp: {
          offset: 32, // number of bytes
          bytes: wallet_address, // base58 encoded string
        },
      },
    ],
  }
);
```

Thanks and best regards,
Kevin

Answer (score 0):

By adding a filter for amount bytes being 0

amount starts at offset 64
https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/6dfc68db1370c65076e8a860db74fd6483161d8a/token/program/src/state.rs#L92

```
  {
    memcmp: {
      offset: 64, // number of bytes
      bytes: '11111111', // base58 encoded amount of 0u64
    },
  },
```

So this would make your call become

```
let programmAccount = await connection.getParsedProgramAccounts(
  TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
  {
    filters: [
      {
        dataSize: 165, // number of bytes
      },
      {
        memcmp: {
          offset: 32, // offset to owner
          bytes: wallet_address, // base58 encoded string
        },
      },
      {
        memcmp: {
          offset: 64, // offset to amount
          bytes: '11111111', // base58 encoded amount of 0u64
        },
      },
    ],
  }
);
```

Note: Offset isn't the number of bytes, it is where to start comparing in the account data

Comment: Hey, its seems to getting into the right direction but I still do not receive any data like in the prior version. I copied your code snippet and I receive for the wallet 4VFLXj98GFPXkXNCKgRWi287UznBvhDLWJe3WNJCZ1Lg two result: https://solscan.io/token/DB9dRiGXouKJ7FawdnvgoYjrW5Aw52dmWZtnd5nHMLNW and https://solscan.io/token/8ViAMbFcxpgm9mXVx7ponuqWYViaWdsf43xHZsEkHANQ. However, I do not receive the other transfered tokens. It should be 10 or more. Furthermore, I do not receive the current tokens with the code snippet. Do you have any further idea? Thanks!